# Loss Function Sum or Mean Region Proposal Network Faster R-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, faster-rcnn

My Region Proposal Network loss function has a low loss.

Evaluate model: 2/2 [==============================] - 1s 30ms/step - loss: 4.3797e-04

However, the predictions it makes are very off. When I visualize the top 10 boxes in terms of confidence, this is what I get:

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX1tq.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oimSP.png)

Something is very wrong. I don't have a way to measure accuracy (since this is regression), but just with a visual look I can tell there is no way that my network outputs can be correct, since all of the boxes I see in all of the images I test are *totally* off.

I suspect the error is within the Region Proposal Network loss function. Here is my loss code:

```
class RPN_Loss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
  def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
    # Calculate binary cross entropy
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

    # Split true and pred tensors into objectness and transform tensors
    transform_true,objectness_true = tf.split(y_true, num_or_size_splits=[4,1],axis=-1)
    transform_pred,objectness_pred = tf.split(y_pred, num_or_size_splits=[4,1],axis=-1)

    # Calculate transform loss
    transform_loss = tf.where(tf.abs(tf.square(transform_pred - transform_true)) < 1, 0.5 * tf.square(transform_pred - transform_true), tf.abs(tf.square(transform_pred - transform_true)) - 0.5)
    transform_loss = tf.where(transform_true != [0,0,0,0], transform_loss * 1/256, 0)

    # Calculate classification loss
    cls_loss = bce(objectness_true, objectness_pred)
    cls_loss = tf.where(objectness_true == 1, (cls_loss) * 1/256, 0) + tf.where(objectness_true == 0, cls_loss * 1/256, 0)
    cls_loss = tf.abs(cls_loss)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(transform_loss) + tf.reduce_mean(cls_loss))
```

Specifically, I think the last line is where the error is. I am not supposed to use reduce_mean, but rather reduce_sum.

The problem is that when I do use reduce_sum instead of reduce_mean, the loss is super high (like 537, nan, or some crazy infinity number).

Another unrelated thing I did is to take the absolute value of the classification loss. I am not sure if this is correct. When I did not do this, the loss gradually diverged to negative infinity, so I figured taking the absolute value would prevent this from happening (which it did).

Here is my network for reference.

```
def get_rpn(feature_map_width,feature_map_height,k):
    num_anchors = feature_map_width*feature_map_height*k
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(feature_map_width, feature_map_height, 3), name="img")
    conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",name='conv2d')(inputs)
    objectness_unshaped = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=k, kernel_size=1, padding="same", name='objectness_unshaped',activation='sigmoid')(conv2d)
     objectness = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((num_anchors,1),name='objectness')(objectness_unshaped)

    transform_unshaped = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=k*4, kernel_size=1, padding="same", name='transform_unshaped',activation="linear")(conv2d)
    transform = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((num_anchors,4),name='transform')(transform_unshaped)

    combined_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1,name='concatenate')([transform,objectness])
    combined_output = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((num_anchors,5),name='combined_output')(combined_output)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=combined_output, name="region_proposal_network")
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.SGD(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE), loss=RPN_Loss())
    return model
```

By the way, I am using a SGD optimizer with a learning rate of 0.025.

Is my loss function coded correctly, or is there something wrong?

As you can see, I am kind of *loss*-t. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to Tensorflow and computer vision and machine learning in general.

Comment: You do not need to use absolute value of the classification loss, you should fix the underlying problem, as it is still there, we can only speculate since you did not include parts of the model, it can be for example using the wrong activation for classification decisions.

Comment: I am using sigmoid for objectness and linear for transforms. Is there perhaps an error with the Reshape?

Comment: Here is the code if you would like to see the entire thing: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EI9S8d78xjPb2j227HcJ2iz76LrBSR5I

Comment: Are my current reduce_mean and reduce_sum functions correct? Was it correct for me to use reduce_mean instead of reduce_sum?